# Creating Nested slices with NgRx store following the lazy modules structure

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store-4.0

I am new to NgRx.
In my project We have 3 levels of lazy Modules. I want the store's state to be nested according to the modules hierarchy but when I am writing: `storeModule.forFeature('child',reducer)`
I am getting a flat slice of state instead of hierarchical one.

For example if I have parent module and a child module. I will define at the parent Module `storeModule.forFeature('father',reducer)`
and in the child module `storeModure.forFeature('child',reducer)`

the result of the state will not be

```
{ father { child {}}}
```

rather it will be:

```
{ father {}, child {}}
```

Is there a way to make the state hierarchical as the way the lazy modules are?

Comment: AFAIK no, there isnt. You  will have to compose the `father` state with the `child` one in order to obtain what you need.

Comment: Thanks Jota. But doesnt it againt what lazy module is all about?
The child state should only appear if the user has navigate to one of the lazy module components.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can have lazy loaded state slices. Imagine you have the following module configuration

```
app
  father
    child
```

And you want (as you described) to have the following state

```
{
  father: {
    child: {}
  }
}
```

You need to ensure that:

- You have a router in the `AppModule` and a Router in the `FatherModule`.
- You lazy load the `FatherModule` in the `AppModules` router(!).
- You lazy load the `ChildModule` in the `FatherModules` router(!).
- The configuration in the imports is correct: In the `ChildModule`: `StoreModule.forFeature('child', childreducers)` and in the `FatherModule`: `StoreModule.forFeature('father', fatherreducers)`.

For example if you navigate to a component in the `FatherModule` it'll load the `father` feature. But not necessarily the `child` feature. Only if you navigate to some subroute which loads the `ChildModule`.

What you currently do is having both `forFeature` methods in the same module. That does not make any sense because the "feature" is directly related to the module.